# Current user only updated after page refresh

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two ul elements that I want to show whether or not the user is logged in. After I login it is showing the first ul; the second ul is not showing until I refresh the page.
When I login the value in "accountService.currentUser" is null, after the reload the value turns to be "[object Object]" and the second ul shows (it should be showing after the redirect to dashboard).

Login method:

```
login(): void {
    this.accService.login(this.model).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
      },
      (error: any) => {}
    );
  }
```

The login service:

```
login(model: any): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
      take(1),
      map((response: User) => {
        const user = response;
        
        if (user) {
          this.setCurrentUser(user);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

The html:

```
<ul *ngIf="(accountService.currentUser$ | async) === null">
  <li><a class="listlink" routerLink="user/login">Entrar</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul *ngIf="(accountService.currentUser$ | async) != null" class="desktop-ul">
  <li routerLinkActive="active"><a class="listlink" data-page="events" routerLink="events/list">Eventos</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I also have this interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

let currentUser: User;

this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
  currentUser = user;

  if (currentUser) {
    request = request.clone(
      {
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

return next.handle(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question with a few informations, but I believe that can be the take(1) the problem, because the currentUser from undefined become null and after come the unsubscribe.

Comment: What information do you need? I tried without the take, still happens the same behaviour